# How to use Foundation 6 Interchange with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the code for Foundation 6 Interchange. I was thinking that it can maybe work with the second piece of code I put but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a better approach to do this?

Zurb Foundation example code

```
  <img data-interchange="[assets/img/interchange/small.jpg, small], [assets/img/interchange/medium.jpg, medium], [assets/img/interchange/large.jpg, large]">
```

Second peace of code

```
 <%= image_path data: {interchange: "[@anime.header_image.url(:large), large]", [@anime.header_image.url(:medium}, medium], [@anime.header_image.url(:small), small] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `image_tag`, not `image_path`

*(written on multiple lines for clarity)*

```
<%= image_tag "",
    data: {
      interchange: "
        [#{@anime.header_image.url(:large)}, large],  
        [#{@anime.header_image.url(:medium)}, medium], 
        [#{@anime.header_image.url(:small)}, small]
      "
    }
%>
```

The first argument is left blank, but that is where you would normally place the `src` attribute value.